# Return month as a text Looker Studio

Tags: looker-studio

I´m trying to use SUBSTR in looker studio. Get the date and show 3 first month letters. Exemple: March. Show "Mar"

But, when I use MONTH(Date), return "March" and when I use SUBSTR(MONTH(Date), 1, 3) return = 3.

Any one knows what´s happening here?

Thank you!!

I´m trying
SUBSTR(MONTH(Mês), 1, 3)

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
FORMAT_DATETIME("%b",Date)
```

- *[Supported format elements](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/format-elements#format_elements_date_time) can be found here*

[image]